# Текст при адаптации

Tags: html, css

как добиться, чтоб текст при адаптации шёл в строчку, а не вот так в колонку по слову? [image: фото с текстом]

Comment: Надо прописать что-то в html и css

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите одну длинную строчку, то этого можно добится при помощи CSS свойства [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```css
element {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

А так у вас похоже ширина родительского элемента, в котором текст, слишком маленькая. Я думаю желаемого результата можно добится легче с помощью flex контейнера.

1. Поставьте один division элемент (который будет flex контейнером).

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
```

2. Добавьте в него ещё два элемента—картинку/что у вас там с "О себе", и текст—каждый в свой division элемент.

```html
<div class="flex">

    <!-- 1-ый дочерний элемент flex контейнера -->
    <div>
        <h1>О себе</h1>
        <img src="..." />
    </div>

    <!-- 2-ой дочерний элемент flex контейнера -->
    <div>
        <p>Живу в .... В сфере ремонта с 2005 года...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Добавьте необходимый CSS.

```css
.flex {
    /* Создаёт flex контейнер */
    display: flex;

    /* Образует колонки а не ряды */
    flex-direction: row;

    /* Выравнивает элементы flex контейнера вертикально к вершине */
    align-items: flex-start;

    /* Выравнивает элементы flex контейнера горизонтально с одинаковым количеством пространства межу ними */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Результат:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div>
        <h1>О себе</h1>
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Живу в .... В сфере ремонта с 2005 года...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Для дальнейшого чтения:

- Flex контейнеры: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flex_Container
- Направление flex контейнеров: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction
- Выравнивание элементов flex котейнера:

  - `align-items`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items
  - `justify-content`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!